# Missing actions dropdown

Tags: export, actions

I am trying to export a list from CiviCRM and I seem to be missing the actions drop-down. I have used this field before, but it has dissappeared. I have attached an image of what my screen currently looks like  when I am doing an advanced search. From memory, the Actions drop-down usually sat underneath the 'edit search criteria' section and above the "A,B,C.." search function. I am using a Macbook and have tried both Firefox and Safari in case the browser is not supported properly, but neither seem to work.
[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: You and Nina both need to provide more information eg what version, and what change has happened between it working and it disappearing?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the problem.  Perhaps this will help you.  On my site, I modified the css to hide some information from the public facing CiviCRM pages. When I did that I also hide the Actions Drop-down. When I commented out this one line, the Actions Drop-down displayed again:

/* .crm-container #search-status {display:none;} */

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4098)

Comment: I just updated my comment and believe it now answers the question and may be useful now.  Do you agree?